Time-Based Trigger Returns Only the Values from Row 1
I have a function that runs based on edits made in Column V starting from Row 2 in a worksheet. That function sends an email on edit.
function onEdit_ColumnV(e){

  if(activeSheetName === targetSheetName && activeRow >= startRow && activeCol === 22 && activeVal !== blank){

    let incidentClassification = targetSheet.getRange(activeRow,7).getValue();
    let incidentDescription = targetSheet.getRange(activeRow,9).getValue();
    let site = targetSheet.getRange(activeRow,3).getValue();
    let subject = "[ SITE " + site + " ] FACILITIES INCIDENT ESCALATION REPORT";
    let main = "<p>Dear Team,</p>" +
      "<p>We are writing to inform you about a recent " + incidentClassification + " - " + incidentDescription + " that occurred in our [Site " + site + "]. Please see incident report below.</p>" +
      "<hr>";
    let closing = "<p>Your cooperation and understanding are greatly appreciated. For any urgent concerns, do not hesitate to contact the facilities management team.</p>" +
      "<p>Best regards,</p>" +
      "<p>[ SITE " + site + " ] Facilities"

    if(incidentClassification === incidentClassification2){

      let htmlBodyN1 = main + notification1_Body() + closing;
      GmailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com",subject,'',{htmlBody: htmlBodyN1});
      setUpTrigger();

    }
  }
}

After sending an initial email which contains the values of the active row in Column V where the edit was made, the function will create a time-based trigger that sends a second email after 20 minutes.
function setUpTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendNotification2")
  .timeBased()
  .after(1000)
  .create();
}

The values of the second email are pulled from the same row of the initial email. Here is function sendNotification2().
function sendNotification2(){

    let incidentClassificationNotif2 = targetSheet.getRange(activeRow,7).getValue();
    let incidentDescriptionNotif2 = targetSheet.getRange(activeRow,9).getValue();
    let siteNotif2 = targetSheet.getRange(activeRow,3).getValue();
    let subjectNotif2 = "[ SITE " + siteNotif2 + " ] FACILITIES INCIDENT ESCALATION REPORT";
    let mainNotif2 = "<p>Dear Team,</p>" +
      "<p>We are writing to inform you about a recent " + incidentClassificationNotif2 + " - " + incidentDescriptionNotif2 + " that occurred in our [Site " + siteNotif2 + "]. Please see incident report below.</p>" +
      "<hr>";
    let closingNotif2 = "<p>Your cooperation and understanding are greatly appreciated. For any urgent concerns, do not hesitate to contact the facilities management team.</p>" +
      "<p>Best regards,</p>" +
      "<p>[ SITE " + siteNotif2 + " ] Facilities"

    let htmlBodyN2 = mainNotif2 + notification2_Body() + closingNotif2;
    GmailApp.sendEmail("dorcasdomingo@gmail.com",subjectNotif2,'',{htmlBody: htmlBodyN2});
  
}

The variable activeRow is declared outside of the functions to be used globally. It's ss.getActiveCell().getRow().
PROBLEM: When I run function sendNotification2 manually, it gets the values of the active row. But when the time-based trigger runs the function, it gets the values of the header row (row 1). I want the second email to contain the values of the active row, not the row header. The documentation states that when time-driven triggers are used, there no active selections detected, how do I make the function to run 20 minutes after the first email was sent and insert the values of the active row in the second email?
I read a lot of articles about time-driven triggers including the documentation.

You should learn more about the triggers event object and use data like e.range.rowStart rather than  using time consuming functions.

To many undefined variables.  Not reproducible

Please add a [mcve]. It should include the variable declarations for all the variables used on the function causing problems. They could use dummy values but those values should help to reproduce the problem.

ss.getActiveCell().getRow() & But when the time-based trigger runs the function, it gets the values of the header row (row 1). I suggest that you read What's the difference between getActiveCell and getCurrentCell in Google Apps Script?, and also try getCurrentCell instead.
